# What are Tags in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework, I have seen a term TAG. What is the use of it.
When and where we can use this TAG?
Can we create or own tags and how?

Comment: Tags are described in the user guide. What part of that documentation do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases):

- Tags are shown in test reports, logs and, of course, in the test
  data, so they provide metadata to test cases.
- Statistics about test cases (total, passed, failed are automatically collected based on tags).
- With tags, you can include or exclude test cases to be executed.
- With tags, you can specify which test cases are considered critical.

and my points how i use:

- Mark tests cases that are not allowed to be re-run at the end
- Mark tests cases that are allowed to be run in parallel
- Add defect ID as tag so I will know which test cases should pass after fix